# Multiple outputs for reactions in node.js with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want the bot to react to a message for a poll with two choices and have users react with the provided emotes aswell but in addition to that I would like to fetch the users id and know who voted for what.
The problem I have now is this: the output for the first poll is:

```
2x the bots id (for both choices)
1x the users id (if they only voted for one choice)
this is how it should be.
```

but when I create another poll after that the output is:

```
4x the bots id 
2x the users id
```

do a third poll after that and it prints out:

```
6x the bots id 
3x the users id 
and so on..
```

So after 3 polls I have the console output of 12x the bots id and 6x the users id in total when it should be just 6x and 3x. I need to restart the bot after each poll in order for it to print out the correct output.
what exactly is going on here and how do I fix it?

index.js:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const tokenfile = require("./token.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdir("./Commands/",(err,files)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    let jsfile = files.filter(f=>f.split(".").pop()==="js")
    if(jsfile.length <= 0){
        console.log("Couldnt find commands.");
        return;
    }
    jsfile.forEach((f, i)=>{
        let props = require(`./Commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${f} loaded!`);
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    });
});

bot.on("ready", async () =>{
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);
});

bot.on("message", async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = tokenfile.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
    if(commandfile) await commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
});

bot.login(tokenfile.token);
```

poll.js:

```
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args)=> {
    let poll = message.content.match(/"(.+?)"/g);
    let bicon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;
    let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setThumbnail(bicon)
        .setColor("#15f153")
        .addField("Created by:", message.author.username)
        .addField("Poll:", poll);
    message.channel.send(botembed)
        .then(async (pollMessage) => {
            await pollMessage.react('✅');
            await pollMessage.react('❌')
        });
    bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {
                console.log(`${user.id}`);
        }

        if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
            console.log(`${user.id}`);
        }
    });
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "poll"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're experiencing is because you're attaching a nested listener to the `messageReactionAdd` event. Each time the bot sees a reaction added *on any message* after that point, it'll call your listener function. That means that after a poll, the bot is still listening to reactions and will keep attaching even more listeners. In fact, after a certain amount of listeners attached, you may see a warning in your console regarding a possible memory leak.

Consider using [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) or directly utilizing a [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector). See the hyperlinked documentation for details and example usage.

Comment: is there a way to stop the ReactionCollector collecting not over time but via a command?

Comment: You could define a property of your bot as an array/map with the collectors so that it's accessible throughout your code, and call `Collector.stop()` on the collector you want to end.

Comment: im sorry to bother but can you maybe tell me or show me examples on how to implement a reactioncollector and how to implement the bot as an array/map with the collectors like you said? I am fairly new to coding..

Comment: [This guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) should be quite useful for implementing the collectors. To keep track of them, take your bot variable (assuming it's named `client` here) and define a property of it as a map `client.collectors = new Map()`. Then you can use `client.collectors.set(pollMessage.id, collector)` (assuming `collector` is a reaction collector). Then to get that collector, you'd use `client.collectors.get('messageIDhere')`. When it expires, you can remove it from the map using `Map.delete()` (used like `Map.get()`).